AWS SES email works from 1 verified identity but not for the other
I am using AWS node-sdk to send emails from my AWS verified SES identities. It works for one identity but not from the other. Both the identities are verified and have exactly the same configurations. I get a success message with a messageID for both of them, However, in case of one identity I receive the email in my inbox but when using the other, I don't receive any email in my inbox.
I am the admin user so have all the permissions. Also all the 3 identities involved here (2 senders and 1 receiver) are all verified using email verification.
What could be the issue here?
